# Highcharts : Tooltip pointFormat decimal to percent

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to use `pointFormat` property to format the tooltips.  The problem with this is that I can not figure out a way to use `{point.y}` (0.0324123) and make it format to a precent (3.24).

As i said above, I have to do this in `tooltip.pointFormat`.  My current code looks like this

```
$highcharts[$key]['tooltip'] = [
    'pointFormat' => '<p style="margin:0;"><span style="color:{series.color};">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:,.2f}%</b></p>'
];
```

Is there a way to do `{point.y:,.2f} * 100` within the html/HighCharts syntax?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `formatter` instead of `pointFormat`? I know you said you "have" to use `pointFormat`, but I just wanted to make sure we're covering all the bases...

Comment: This is because i am making the options array in PHP and passing it to javascript.  you can not pass function this way.

Comment: I usually solve this problem (the passing stuff from PHP one) by having two javascript objects. One of them is hard-coded in the javascript and contains anything that won't be changing... that's formatter functions, most of the setup for the chart, etc. I have another javascript object that contains changing values (e.g., the data, labels, etc.) that need to be generated by PHP. I then merge the two objects together before rendering the chart. See here for how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: `pointFormat` can only set simple patterns, it won't accept any calculations. For such purposes you indeed need to use `formatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this further, there is not way to use 'pointFormat' and multiple (convert to percent).

Solution: DO not use 0.035, use 3.50.  If you do this, Highcharts will format the Axis correctly.

Edit:
Rahul Gupta Posted below with a way to do this using for Formatter if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/9VKs8/)**
You will have to use `tooltip.formatter` option like this (will return value truncated upto two decimal places):

```
tooltip: {
                //valueSuffix: '°C',
                enabled: true,
                formatter:function(){
                  return '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">'+this.series.name+'</span>: <b>'+Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y*100),2,'.')+'%</b>';
                }
            },
```

Comment: My dear friend, you will have to understand that `tooltip.pointFormat` does not provide flexibility to perform mathematical calculation on the values as provided by `tooltip.formatter` option. And after all what you want is to display the formatted values in the tooltip, right ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to return value in percentage truncated upto two decimal places